# getting the value of the DropdownList ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, dropdownlistfor

I have the following loop which is displaying multiple DropdownLists

```
             @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PositionAttribsMultiplierDef.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.PositionAttribsMultiplierDef[i].PositionId)</td>
                    @for (int j = 0; j < Model.PositionAttribsMultiplierDef[i].AttribsByPosition.Count; j++)
                    {
                        <td>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AttribId, new SelectList(new[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" },
                            Model.PositionAttribsMultiplierDef[i].AttribsByPosition[j].AttributePlayerPosMult.ToString()),
                             new { id = Model.PositionAttribsMultiplierDef[i].PositionId + "_" + 
                                 Model.PositionAttribsMultiplierDef[i].AttribsByPosition[j].AttributeId})
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
```

And I am managing to get the selected value in the model, where I have :-

```
public string[] AttribId { get; set; }
```

Now I wish to also get the ID of the DropDownList, so that I can attach this AttribID, which is for example "0", or "1", or "2" etc to the ID, which will be something like "CB_Cor".

So Ideally I wish to get a value such as "2_CB_Cor", and then I can parse that value and insert it into the database.

So my question is, how can I attach this value

```
new { id = Model.PositionAttribsMultiplierDef[i].PositionId + "_" + 
                                 Model.PositionAttribsMultiplierDef[i].AttribsByPosition[j].AttributeId}
```

to the m.AttribId

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: A select only posts back its value (i.e. the value of the selected option), not the `id` attribute. You could generate a `SelectList` (on the controller) and set the `Value` (and `Text`) property to the value(s) you want to post back.

Comment: ok then I will have to loop through the string[] object to get my values